# How to replace variable value inside cons cell in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to do something like this

```
(cons '(someword,string->symbol somevarname) (restoflist))
```

but somevarname is never replaced by its value.

I thought this was possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, but because you quoted the expression containing `string->symbol`, it never got evaluated.  I'd try to show the right way to get what you want, but it isn't clear just what that is.

Based on your comment (and ignoring the comma), it seems that you would want:

```
(cons (list 'someword (string->symbol "somevarname")) restoflist)
```

Comment: I would like to build a list where the first cell is (flower, symbol of variable value) and add it to (1  2 3) say to produce ((flower,symbol of variable value) 1 2 3).

Comment: @user35202 It's unclear why you have a comma there. Do you literally want a comma in your output?

Comment: @AlexisKing Yes. I want my final list to look like '((SUN,blue) 2 3 4) say.

Comment: @user35202 Why do you want the comma? Why not just have the output be `'((SUN blue) 2 3 4)`?

Comment: Does this mean `(SUN,blue)` is a list of 3 items (SUN, comma, and blue) or something else?

Comment: @AlexisKing Basically I would like to cons a cell that can have 3 symbols? SUN , and blue?

Answer (score 1):

Quote makes literal lists. To make a list dynamically at runtime, you can also use quasiquote and unquote. For your case, it looks something like the following (assume `somevarname` is either locally or globally bound):

```
(cons `(someword ,(string->symbol somevarname)) (restoflist))
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me (it doesnt evaluate somevarname) unless I am missing something

Comment: did you properly put [\`] instead of [']? and somevarname must be bound by `let` or `define`. the following expression works fine:  (let ((somevarname "foo")) (cons `(someword ,(string->symbol somevarname)) (restoflist)))